# Deletion an element of an `ArrayList` and setting the info to a layout in `MainActivity` by the command of a custom `Dialog`

Tags: java, android, arraylist, layout, dialog

I am new working with this customized `Dialog` in android. I may not be able to clarify my problem properly by writing, So it humble request to understand what i want from given code.

In `MainActivity` i have `Button` to delete an element of an `ArrayList` and setting the info from the `ArrayList` to a `Layout`.

Code from CustomDialog:

```
public class PermissionToDelete extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

public Button btnYes, btnNo;
public TextView txtPermToDelete;

public PermissionToDelete(Context context){
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.permission_delete);
    initialize();

}

public void initialize(){
    btnYes = findViewById(R.id.btnYes);
    btnNo = findViewById(R.id.btnNo);
    txtPermToDelete = findViewById(R.id.txtPermToDelete);

    btnYes.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnNo.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnNo){
        dismiss();
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnYes){
        MainActivity.deleteOrErase = "delete";
        dismiss();
    }

}
```

}

There is a static String variable in `MainActivity` named `deleteOrErase`.
From dialog it returns the string `delete` if `Button` `Yes` is clicked.

Code from `MainActivity`:

```
tv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                String text = tv.getText().toString();

                PermissionToDelete permissionToDelete = new PermissionToDelete(MainActivity.this);

                permissionToDelete.show();


                if(deleteOrErase.equals("delete")){

                    String index = "";
                    for(int i = 1; text.charAt(i) != ')'; i++){
                        index += text.charAt(i);
                    }

                    tasksList.remove(Integer.parseInt(index) - 1);

                    File rootFile = new File(rootFolder);
                    if(rootFile.exists()){
                        String[]entries = rootFile.list();
                        for(String s: entries){
                            File currentFile = new File(rootFile.getPath(),s);
                            currentFile.delete();
                        }
                        rootFile.delete();
                    }
                    dailyTasksLayout.removeAllViews();

                    makePrimaryFileAndFolder();

                    saveDataToFile();

                    setTaskList();

                    deleteOrErase = "";
                }
```

But the problem is before button from `dialog` is clicked, `if(deleteOrErase.equals("delete"))` is encountered when the value of `deleteOrErase` is still null.
Therefore data isn't deleted at the first click.
Its need second click to delete, because now the value of `deleteOrErase` is "delete".

How can i delete it from first click?
Or is there any other way???

thanks dear honorable members! <3

(I don't know either i could clarify my problem or not.
Even i can't understand from mty writings :P )

Comment: @SaadAAkash
I hope you can help.

Comment: @Md. Rejaul Karim